# Calling li from dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div and then dynamically generating several divs within, so it looks somethings like this generated:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="other"></div>
  <div class="items">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using `.append` on `$(".info")` to insert both the div's and li's (in one of them). My problem is to make li's clickable. As they are dynamically generated (as well as their parent `$(".items")`), this doesn't work:

```
$(".items").on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log("val"); 
});
```

Edit: Hey, I've changed div to ul, so it's generated:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="other"></div>
  <ul class="items">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, my previous js still doesn't work. Trying now all your suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Your code works, what's the problem?

Comment: `$(".items").on('click', 'li'` Why do you have the li there?

Comment: @CharlieFish read about event delegations with jQuery!

Comment: `li` is supposed inside of `ul` or `ol`, maybe your works, but for the HTML to be valid.

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.items li', function(e){}) should work. This delegates the event to the body, meaning that even the events that aren't there yet will work

Comment: @eisbehr I understand that. Maybe I'm just not understanding the question and what the end goal is. I don't exactly see what the problem is.

Comment: And you have `<li>` inside a `<div>`. You sure? `<ul>` ??

Comment: Hey, @eisbehr code does't work as items was dynamically generated. As for the li not being used in divs, i didn't know, so changed to ul, as you pointed out! However, js from above still doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer. @Ilya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the event delegation to `.info`, `body` or `document`, because you even generate `.items` dynamically. And `li` is only valid inside an `ul`.

```js
$(".info").on('click', '.items li', function(e) {
    console.log("val"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info">
  <div class="other"></div>
  <ul class="items">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I didn't know that I can pass .items li not just the li element. Btw do you know is there any limit? I mean how many div can be passed? Smth like this: '.items .some .another li' will work too? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The selector belongs to your html. So yes, it could work, if your html is matchig the selector. @Ilya

Answer (score 0):

I have edited it with working example.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    console.log("val"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div class="info">
  <div class="other"></div>
  <ul class="items">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for -1 voting.

Answer (score -1):

Use `this` in scope to access the clicked element.

```js
$(".items").on('click', 'li', function() {
  alert("You clicked on '#" + this.innerHTML + "'");
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <div class="other"></div>
  <div class="items">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also `<li>` inside `<div>` is weird right?  :) :). Add that to your answer too. And I am not the one to downvote btw ;)

Comment: Hey, I didn't know regarding the <li> not being used in <div>, but it worked for me anyways. As for the JS, the problem here is with event handler, so your code will not work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.items li', function(e){})
```

should work. This delegates the event to the body, meaning that even the events that aren't there yet will work.

```js
var container = $('.container');
var child = $('<div />').addClass('child').text('Click me');
child.appendTo(container);

$('body').on('click', '.child', function(e){
    alert('It works ;)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to know why the downvotes. It's basically the same answer as the accepted one (except mine came earlier).